# Regular Expression in Word VBA

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have the following regular expression syntax in VBA for MS Word which works:

```
regEx.Pattern = "\w*\(\w*\s[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3}(\)|\-[0-9]{1,3}\))"
MsgBox regEx.test("This is a test (Chronicles 13:12-14)")
```

This returns True, as desired. I encounter difficulty when I attempt to include patterns for "First", "Second", "Third", 1, 2, 3, or nothing immediately following my opening parenthesis. I have tried `[First|Second|Third|1|2|3]`? but that returns false when I add any of those strings/numbers inside the parenthesis. What am I missing?

Thanks for the explanations and suggestion. I added a final "|" without anything after it to account for the lack of any of the numbers. I also had to add spaces in each option. The final working version is 
`"\w*\((First |Second |Third |[1-3] |)\w*\s[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,3}(\)|\-[0-9]{1,3}\))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes (`[]`) match literally any of the contained characters. Because of that, `[First|Second|Third|1|2|3]` matches `F`, `i`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `|`, `S`, etc.

You'll want to use alternation outside of the character class. You can group this using `(...)` or if you want a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.

Try replacing `[First|Second|Third|1|2|3]` with `(?:First|Second|Third|[1-3])`.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, and it solves the dilemma relating to First|Second|etc. But I also need it to return True if none of these are present (as in original example).

Comment: Since I already have this in a (non-capturing) group, you can just add a `?` to qualify the entire group as optional. Just like `abc?` would match `a`, `b`, and an optional `c`...`foo(?:bar)?` would match `foo` with an optional `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to use `OR` operand you shouldn't put your words within a character class. instead you can use a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) :

```
(First|Second|Third|1|2|3)
```

Because inside a character class the regex engine assume your pattern as any combination between the characters of your words and the character `|`.

For better understanding see the following diagrams :

```
[First|Second|Third|1|2|3]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FLZUeqDnSXlZb6_a)

---

```
(First|Second|Third|1|2|3)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JSxIyrQtU8kGlHQz)